# What is the "coefficient of ionization" or "ionization coefficient"?

Tags: acid-base

The [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95681/calculating-ph-is-my-answer-correct) got bumped and I looked at it. The OP seems to use the two terms *coefficient of ionization* and *ionization coefficient* interchangeably and assigns the variable $\alpha$. The problem is in part asking about the pH of a 0.1 molar ammonia solution.

Am I correct to assume that the *ionization coefficient* is the fraction of the ammonia that has ionized?

My google foo is off today. I couldn't find a formula anywhere where the context made sense. The problem in question has nothing to do with a plasma.

Comment: `Am I correct to assume that the ionization coefficient is the fraction of the ammonia that has ionized?`  Yes.

Comment: It's degree not coefficient.

Comment: @Mithoron _ Thanks! I now suspect that the OP in the original problem may have translated it from another language and used an uncommon term.