# Problem in terms of pC-pH plotting

Tags: environmental-chemistry

I recently confronted a mission to plot a pC-pH graph('p' stands for the p-value notation, and 'C' stands for the concentration of a species), which meets the conditions below:

- **Plot the pC-pH graph when a monoprotic acid is added - salts and strong acids can be co-added.**

Therefore, I initally assumed that the monoprotic acid to be $\ce{CH3COOH}$, strong acid to be $\ce{HNO3}$, and the salt to be $\ce{NaCl}$ in order to avoid the overlapping of the species.

But it led me to so much unknowns: so I changed the species to $\ce{CH3COOH}$, $\ce{HCl}$, $\ce{CH3COONa}$ each. However it still didn't quite work out. Is it even possible to plot this?

This is actually supposed to be an environmental engineering problem, so there might be some assumptions which won't make the circumstance way accurate but make it simpler.

Comment: Have a look at the answers https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60068/how-to-set-up-equation-for-buffer-reaction/95566 and  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/100346/calculate-ph-of-a-mixture-of-a-strong-base-and-acid-knowing-only-the-ph-wt-v/100355#100355

Comment: @porphyrin So I know that those cases, especially the former one 'How to set up equation for buffer reaction?' is theoretically pointing the same notions as what I've asked. But the condition is different: in this case I have one more initial species and that's why I'm having trouble.