# Can Acids have pH of more than 7?

Tags: acid-base, ph

Consider a solution of $\text{HCl}$ with a concentration of $10^{-10}$ $\text{M}$. Now, if I find it's pH:
$$\begin{aligned}\text{pH} &= -\log([\text{H}^+])\\
\text{pH} &= -\log(10^{-10}) = 10\end{aligned}$$
At room temperature, $\text{pH} + \text{pOH} = 14 \implies \text{pOH}$ of the given acid is $4$. This means that the $[\text{OH}^-]$ ions is $10^{-4}$ $\text{M}$. But from where do these $\text{OH}^-$ ions come?

Comment: At this dilution rates you can no longer get away with using concentration instead of *activity*, and you have to calculate $\mathrm{pH}$ as $\mathrm{pH} = -\log a(\ce{H+}).$ Note that $\mathrm{pH}$ also heavily relies on solvent/medium.

Comment: I object. At dilutions this great, you can **more than ever**  rely on using concentration instead of activity. Now to the point. What is the pH of pure water?

Comment: @andselisk right answer, but to another question ;-)

Comment: In one word: *Autoprotolyis*

Comment: ^ That said, I think this is a useful duplicate for search, concisely worded.

Comment: In acid base reactions in water there is always the reaction $\ce{H2O <=> H^+ + OH^-}$ occurring and this cannot be ignored. The equilibrium constant $K_w=10^{14}$ so the $\ce{[H^+]}=10^{-7}$ from this reaction far exceeds that from $10^{-10} $ molar acid. see answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/100346/calculate-ph-of-a-mixture-of-a-strong-base-and-acid-knowing-only-the-ph-wt-v/100355#100355