# Calculating the pH of an exteremely dilute solution (3.6×10^-9 M) of weak acid

Tags: acid-base, analytical-chemistry, ph

I've got a question about analytical chemistry that I'm having trouble solving:

> For a $\pu{3.6 \times 10^{-9} M}$ solution of 1-naphthoic acid, calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ $\left(K_\mathrm{a} = 2.1 \times 10^{-4} \right).$

I attempted to solve using an ICE table and then solving for $x$. Then solving for $\mathrm{pH}$ from there. I was able to solve the first part of the question that way (concentration was $\pu{0.048 M}$ and the $\mathrm{pH}$ was 2.51).

However, I keep getting a $\mathrm{pH}$ of 8.44 and this is incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have forgotten to include autoionization of pure water.

Comment: Could you clearly state your calculations? I know you probably got 8.44 from $\mathrm{-log(3.6\cdot10^{-9})}$ and 2.51 from $\ce{[H+]^2 = (0.048)(2.1 x 10^{-4})}$, but they don't really make sense with this context as such a small concentration of a weak acid won't change the pH by anything really

Comment: It should be clear pH must be just slightly below 7 and that we can consider near all acid to be dissociated. Then you can consider it as the case of very diluted strong acid. Kw=[H+][OH-]=[H+]([H+]-c).

Comment: Have a look at this answer  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/100346/calculate-ph-of-a-mixture-of-a-strong-base-and-acid-knowing-only-the-ph-wt-v/100355#100355 and this one https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60068/how-to-set-up-equation-for-buffer-reaction/95566#95566 for general method to solve these kinds of problems.