# Why does pH of a buffer solution change according to Henderson–Hasselbalch equation?

Tags: acid-base, ph

If I add a little amount of acid or base to a buffer solution, the pH of the buffer won't change. That's what the diagramatic mechanism tells us.

But according to Henderson–Hasselbalch equation, the $\mathrm{pH}$ changes!

For example, a buffer solution of $\ce{CH3COOH}$ and $\ce{CH3COONa}$:

$$\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log\left(\frac{[\ce{CH3COONa}]}{[\ce{CH3COOH}]}\right)$$

Now I add a little amount of acid $(\pu{0.01M},\;\pu{5 mL}).$ It disturbs $\ce{CH3COONa}$. Reaction:

$$\ce{CH3COONa + HCl -> CH3COOH + H2O}$$

It is noticed here that a small amount of $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is produced and a little amount of $\ce{CH3COONa}$ is spared. So simply $[\ce{CH3COOH}]$ and $[\ce{CH3COONa}]$ go high and low, respectively. As a result, the ratio between $\ce{CH3COONa}$ and $\ce{CH3COOH}$ decreases. As the $\mathrm{pH}$ depends on the ratio, the $\mathrm{pH}$ changes as well.
[image]

Comment: First, Henderson–Hasselbalch equation is: $\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log \left(\frac{[\text{base}]}{[\text{acid}]}\right)$. Second, $\frac{[\text{base}]}{[\text{acid}]}$ ratio is in log scale so numerical value of change is minimal at $\mathrm{pH} $ around $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$.

Comment: so Log ([base]/[acid]) is minimal but not 0.  Still a little  change at pH but according to mechanism there shouldn't be any change in pH, shouldn't it? Don't these two ideas contradict each other?

Comment: Do your calculations with suggested change (adding $\ce{HCl}$), and see what happens.

Comment: Yes I did before asking this question and got a little change around 1.8*10^(-3). If add more acid, the change is more

Comment: Your premise re: *"If I add a little amount of acid or base to a buffer solution, the pH of the buffer won't change."* is wrong. The pH does change, just not by much. The gist is that the pH of a buffer solution changes much less than the pH of pure water would. Also look up "buffer capacity."

Comment: There is a worked examples in this answer to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60068/how-to-set-up-equation-for-buffer-reaction/95566

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a $\pu{1.0 L}$ of acetate buffer solution made by $\pu{500.0 mL}$ of $\pu{1.0 M}$ $\ce{CH3COONa}$ solution adding to $\pu{500.0 mL}$ of $\pu{1.0 M}$ $\ce{CH3COOH}$ solution. Thus, $[\ce{CH3COOH}] = [\ce{CH3COONa}] = \pu{0.5 M}$. Therefore, according to Henderson–hasselbalch equation, $\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 4.75$ ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 4.75$ for acetic acid).

Now you add a little amount of acid ($\pu{0.01M}, \; \pu{5 mL}$). It disturbs the equilibrium and change both $[\ce{CH3COONa}]$ and $[\ce{CH3COOH}]$, according to the reaction:

$$\ce{CH3COONa + HCl -> CH3COOH + H2O}$$

Now, the amount of $[\ce{CH3COONa}]$ is reduced by $\pu{0.01M} \times \pu{0.005 L} = \pu{0.00005 mol}$ and, similarly, $[\ce{CH3COOH}]$ is increased by $\pu{0.00005 mol}$.

Hence, new $[\ce{CH3COONa}]$ is $\pu{0.49995 mol/L}$ and $[\ce{CH3COOH}]$ is $\pu{0.50005 mol/L}$ (neglecting the volume change for convenience). Thus, new $\mathrm{pH}$:

$$\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log \left(\frac{[\ce{CH3COONa}]}{[\ce{CH3COOH}]}\right)= 4.75 + \log \left(\frac{\pu{0.49995 mol/L}}{\pu{0.50005 mol/L}}\right) = 4.7499 \approx 4.75$$

You see, it is a very minimal change. It is true that if you add more acid or base, change could be significant. However, all buffers have buffer capacity (usually, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} \pm 1$). Nobody ever said $\mathrm{pH}$ of buffer is constant. It fluctuate withing the capacity. If you add too much acid or base, its $\mathrm{pH}$ would drastically change.

Comment: You have just avoided my question. I acknowledge it's a minimal change but not 0 . The mechanism shows all H+ added get neutralised , no extra  H+ left. Then how and why does this minimal change happen?

Comment: See my last paragraph.

Comment: The mechanism also includes that the system has reached a new equilibrium state in line with the  minimal change in pH

Comment: I am a bit confused at this point that "How does the mechanism include minimal change in pH?"

Comment: Your buffer has $\ce{CH3CO2H}$ and  $\ce{CH3CO2Na}$ in equilibrium with water. Their concentrations will adjust according to the changes following  Le Chatelier principle.

Comment: After adding acid, a little amount of **CH3CO2H** is produced and its concentration gets high. That's why dissociation of **CH3CO2H** happen to gain equilibrium state according to **Le Chatelier principle**.     Is that the reason of minimal change at pH?