# The pH of a drop of water containing ammonia

Tags: kinetics, ph, concentration, environmental-chemistry

Presented with the following equations: What would the $\mathrm{pH}$ of a drop of water be, while in equilibrium with $\ce{NH3(g)}$ at a concentration of $\pu{150 ppb}$?

$$\ce{NH3_{(g)} + H2O_{(l)} <=> NH3_{(aq)} + H2O} \qquad K_\mathrm{H} = \pu{1.76 \cdot 10^{-2} M/atm}$$

$$\ce{NH4+_{(aq)} <=> NH3_{(aq)} + H+}  \qquad K_\mathrm{a} = 5.62 \cdot 10^{-10}$$

So my issue is that I don't know how to express the concentration of $\ce{[NH4+]}$.

Calculating the concentration of $\ce{NH3_{(aq)}}$ is simple: $K_\mathrm{H} \cdot P_\ce{NH3}$, while $P_\ce{NH3} = C \cdot P_\mathrm{air} = 150 \cdot 10^{-9} \cdot \pu{1atm}$, yields $\ce{NH3_{(aq)}} = \pu{2.64 \cdot 10^{-9} M}$.

If we are to tally up all contributions of $\ce{H+}$ then we get:
$\ce{[H+]} = K_\mathrm{w}/\ce{[H+]}$ (from water dissociation) + $K_\mathrm{a} \ce{[NH4+]}/\ce{[H+]}$.

Then $\ce{[H+]} = (K_\mathrm{w} + K_\mathrm{a}\ce{[NH4]})^{0.5}$ and we'd get the $\mathrm{pH}$.

I'm stuck unsure how to express $\ce{[NH4]}$.

Comment: The provided Kh must be errorneous, considering the huge solubility of ammonia in water.

Comment: **HINT** You don't know $\ce{[NH4+], [H+], [OH-]}$ -- So you need three independent equations.

Comment: There is a general way to solve these type of problems, see the answers here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60068/how-to-set-up-equation-for-buffer-reaction/95566

Comment: Well, I decided to look at the dissociation of ammonia instead: NH3+H2O <->NH4(+)+OH(-), using Kb (Kw/Ka). We get 1 mol each of OH- and ammonium ion, so with my given data of NH3 conc (2.64*10^-9 M), I arrived at pOH=6.66 or pH=7.33.

Comment: @porphyrin isn't this way applicable only when you have the concentrations of both acid+conj base or base+conj acid? in my case we only know the conc. of the conj. base of ammonium ion.

Comment: It still applies, you have $\ce{NH3, NH4+,  H+, OH-}$. As the $\ce{NH3}$ concentration is so small so that approximately $\ce{[H+]=[OH-]= 10^{-7} }$  you know that the pH is going to be approximately 7.