# pH for an HA/NaA solution using a contour map

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, ph

The following question has troubled me for a while now.

> A virtual weak acid $\ce{HA}$ dissociates as follows:
>
> $\ce{HA <=> H^+ + A^-}$
>
> with the acid dissociation constant $K_\mathrm{a} = 10^{-3.00}$.
>
> A solution is prepared using a given concentration of $\ce{HA}$, $C_\ce{HA}$ , and a given concentration of its conjugate base salt $\ce{NaA}$, $C_\ce{NaA}$. The pH of the solution depends on these concentrations. The dependence of the pH on $\mathrm{p}C_\ce{HA} (= −\log C_\ce{HA}$) and $\mathrm{p}C_\ce{NaA} (= −\log C_\ce{NaA}$) is
> shown as a contour map below. A doubling in $C_\ce{HA}$ corresponds to a $–0.30$ shift of $\mathrm{p}C_\ce{HA}$ to the left in this contour map.
>
> [image]
>
> **Figure 1.** Contour map of pH for an $\ce{HA/NaA}$ solution.
>
> In this case $C_\ce{NaA}$ is ideally zero and can be neglected. In the above contour map, this situation corresponds to either region $A$, $B$, or $C$, where $\mathrm{p}C_\ce{NaA}$ is large and the following inequalities for $\mathrm{p}C_\ce{HA}$ hold:
>
> **Region A:** $\mathrm{p}C_\ce{HA} < \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$
>
> **Region B:** $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} < \mathrm{p}C_\ce{HA} < \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{w}/2$
>
> **Region C:** $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{w}/2 < \mathrm{p}C_\ce{HA}$
>
> Derive analytical solutions for the pH as a function of $\mathrm{p}C_\ce{HA}$ using the charge balance equation:
>
> $[\ce{H^+}] = [\ce{OH^-}] + [\ce{A^-}]$
>
> combined with the above inequalities for each Region. Because doubling $C_\ce{HA}$ corresponds to a $–0.30$ shift in $\mathrm{p}C_\ce{HA}$ as described above, the pH shift can be determined from the derived analytical
> solutions. **Calculate** the pH shift when $C_\ce{HA}$ is doubled for Regions $A$, $B$, and $C$, respectively.

I was able to get the charge balance equation into the following form using $K_\mathrm{a}$ and $K_\mathrm{w}$:
$[\ce{H^+}]^2 = K_\mathrm{w} + K_\mathrm{a}C_\ce{HA}$

$$\mathrm{pH} = \frac{\mathrm{-lg}(K_\mathrm{w} + K_\mathrm{a}C_\ce{HA})}{2}\tag{1}$$

Using this I calculated the pH for region $A$ and got

$$\mathrm{pH} = \frac{\mathrm{-lg}(10^{-14}+10^{-3}\cdot10^{-(1-0.3)})}{2} = 1.85$$

Is this reasoning correct or am I understanding something incorrectly?

Comment: Your equation (1) is wrong: the log of a sum is not the sum of the logs.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, corrected it by editing the post,

Comment: Your second equation  is mathematically still horribly wrong.

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: The general method described here might help https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60068/how-to-set-up-equation-for-buffer-reaction/95566 (Don't be put of by the title)