# Finding the pOH of a buffer from the scratch without the Henderson Hasselbalch equation

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, buffer

I found this question on the internet that said:

> Find the pOH of the solution obtained by mixing $\pu{0.1 mol}$ of $\mathrm{NH_4 OH}$ $(K_\mathrm b = 10^{-5})$ and $\pu{0.1 mol}$ of $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ in a $\pu{500 mL}$ solution.

What my approach was to do it without applying the Henderson Hasselbalch equation and doing it from the scratch using the "common ion" effect. Here is how I did it:

$\ce{NH4OH}$ is a weak acid and $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ is a strong electrolyte.

$\alpha$= The dissociation constant per mole

$$\ce{NH4OH <<=> NH4+ + OH-}$$

\begin{array}{l|c|c|c} \hline
n_\mathrm{initial} & 0.1& 0 &0\\
n_\mathrm{equilibrium} &0.1(1-\alpha) &0.1\alpha& 0.1\alpha \\
\hline
\end{array}

$$\ce{(NH4)2SO4 -> 2 NH4+ + SO4^2-}$$

\begin{array}{l|c|c|c} \hline
n_\mathrm{initial} & 0.1& 0 &0\\
n_\mathrm{dissociation} &0 &0.2 & 0.1\\
\hline
\end{array}

Now, we can say that
$$K_\mathrm b = \frac{[\ce{NH4+}] [\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{NH_4OH}]}$$

$$10^{-5}= \frac{\dfrac{0.2+0.1 \alpha}{0.5} \times \dfrac{0.1 \alpha}{0.5}}{\dfrac{0.1}{0.5}}$$

As, $\alpha$ is very small for a weak acid, $0.1 \alpha \approx 0$.
Doing the further calculations, we get:

$$\boxed{\alpha = \frac{5}{2} \times 10^{-5}}$$

$$\implies \boxed{\ce{[OH-]} = 0.1 \alpha = \frac{5}{2} \times 10^{-6} \frac{\pu{mol}}{\pu{500 mL}}}$$

Now, $$\mathrm p\ce{OH}=\log[\ce{OH-}] = -[\log(5)-\log(2)-6] = \boxed{5.6}$$

But if we directly apply the Henderson Hasselbalch equation for the buffer, we get:

$$\mathrm p\ce{OH} = \mathrm pK_\mathrm b + \log\left(\frac{[\mathrm{salt}]}{[\mathrm{base}]}\right)$$
$$\mathrm p\ce{OH} = 5 + \log\left(\frac{\dfrac{0.2}{0.5}}{\dfrac{0.1}{0.5}} \right) = 5+ \log(2)=\boxed{5.3}$$
[.] = molarity

Where did I go wrong in the calculation or what mistake did I do while solving this question?

Comment: Using photos/screenshots of text ( especially if handwritten ) instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, cannot be reused nor referred in answers. Additionally, it  can be challenge to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of the essential parts and using of [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) for eventual formatting of mathematical/chemical formulas or equations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Poutnik. So shall I delete the question or edit it and try to write it down in the form of LaTeX?

Comment: Rather edit it, using MathJax with mhchem extension.  [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).  

See also [upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Poutnik I do not know how to write the moles initial and at the equilibrium, there seem to be nothing I can do about it.

Comment: Note that $K_\mathrm{b, \ce{NH3}}=\pu{e-5}$ is wrong and $\ce{NH4OH}$ does not exist. $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}=4.75$, so $K_\mathrm{b}=\pu{10^{-4.75}}$

Comment: It is $\ce{NH_3 + H_2O -> NH_4^{+} + OH^{-}}$ and hence we can define K_b for it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124175/discussion-between-finalboss-and-poutnik).

Comment: There is a general method described here and in the comments ( don't be put off by the title) https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60068/how-to-set-up-equation-for-buffer-reaction/95566

Comment: @porphyrin it still doesn't answer why do I have different answers with different methods opted.

Comment: The method I showed does work with base 0.4 M. and acid 0.2 M, (answer = 5.301) so you will get the correct answer and can then look for errors in your calculation

Answer (score 1):

I found out where the mistake was in my method while solving the question. Here it goes.

• $\ce{NH4OH}$ is a weak acid and $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ is a strong electrolyte.

• $\alpha$= The dissociation constant per mole.

$$\ce{NH4OH <<=> NH4+ + OH-}$$

\begin{array}{l|c|c|c} \hline
n_\mathrm{initial} & 0.1& 0 &0\\
n_\mathrm{equilibrium} &0.1(1-\alpha) &0.1\alpha& 0.1\alpha \\
\hline
\end{array}

$$\ce{(NH_4)_2SO_4 -> 2 NH_4^{+} + SO4^{2-}}$$

\begin{array}{l|c|c|c} \hline
n_\mathrm{initial} & 0.1& 0 &0\\
n_\mathrm{dissociation} &0 &0.2 & 0.1\\
\hline
\end{array}

Now, we can say that:
$$K_\mathrm b = \frac{[\ce{NH4+}] [\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{NH_4OH}]}$$

Plugging in the values mentioned and derived,

$$10^{-5}= \left(\frac{\dfrac{0.2+0.1 \alpha}{0.5} \times \dfrac{0.1 \alpha}{0.5}}{\dfrac{0.1(1-\alpha)}{0.5}}\right)$$

As $\alpha$ is very small for a weak acid, $0.1 \alpha \approx 0$ and $(1- \alpha) \approx 1$. Doing the calculations above, we get that:

$$\boxed{\alpha = \frac{5}{2} \times 10^{-5}}$$
Which further implies that, there are $0.1 \alpha$ moles of $\ce{OH^{-}}$ ions in the 0.5L solution.

$$ \therefore \ \boxed{\ce{[OH-]} = \frac{0.1 \alpha \ \text{mol}}{0.5 \ \text{L}} = \frac{0.1}{0.5} \cdot \frac{5}{2} 10^{-5} = \frac{10^{-5}}{2} \frac{\text{mol}}{\text{L}}}$$

Now, $$\text{pOH} = -\log{[\ce{OH^{-}}]}= -\log{\left(\frac{10^{-5}}{2}\right)}= -[-\log(2)-5]=\boxed{5.3}$$

Answer (score 0):

> Find the $\mathrm{pOH}$ of the solution obtained by mixing $\pu{0.1 mol}$ of $\ce{NH4OH}$ $(K_\mathrm{b} = 10^{-5})$ and $\pu{0.1 mol}$ of $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ in a $\pu{500 mL}$ solution.

OP wants to find $\mathrm{pOH}$ without applying Henderson-Hasselbalch equation, and to do it from the scratch. Here is how I would did it:

Aqueous ammonia solution, still erroneously called it as $\ce{NH4OH}$, is a weak base, and $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ is a strong electrolyte of conjugate acid of aqueous ammonia. In aqueous solution, $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ is completely dissociate:

$$\ce{(NH4)2SO4(aq) -> 2 NH4+(aq) + SO4^2-(aq)}$$

The molarity of each of $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ and aqueous ammonia is $\dfrac{0.1}{0.5} = \pu{0.2 M}$. Accordingly, initial concentration of $\ce{NH4+}$ due to $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ dissociation is $\pu{0.4 M}$. Hence:

$$\begin{array}{l|c|c|c}
 & [\ce{(NH4)2SO4}] & [\ce{NH4+}] & [\ce{SO4^2-}]\\
\hline
n_\mathrm{ini.} & 0.2 & 0 & 0\\
n_\mathrm{diss.} & 0 & 0.4 & 0.2\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The ionization of ammonia in water can be written as:

$$\ce{NH3 (aq) + H2O (l) <=> NH4+ (aq) + OH- (aq)}$$

If $\alpha$ is the amount of ammonia ionized to give $\ce{NH4+}$ ion in $\pu{M}$:

$$\begin{array}{l|c|c|c} 
& [\ce{NH3}] & [\ce{NH4+}] & [\ce{OH-}]\\
\hline
n_\mathrm{ini.} & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0\\
n_\mathrm{equi.} & (0.2 - \alpha) & (0.4 + \alpha) & \alpha \\
\hline
\end{array} $$

By definition,

$$K_\mathrm b = \frac{[\ce{NH4+}] [\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{NH3}]}$$

$$10^{-5} = \frac{(0.4 + \alpha) \times \alpha}{0.2 - \alpha}$$

Since $\alpha \lt \lt 0.2$ for a weak base, $(0.2 - \alpha) \approx 0.2$ and $(0.4 + \alpha) \approx 0.4$.

$$\therefore \ 10^{-5} = \frac{0.4 \times \alpha}{0.2} \ \Rightarrow \ \alpha = 10^{-5} \times \frac{0.2}{0.4} \tag1$$

Since $\alpha = [\ce{OH-}]$, we can rewrite the equation $(1)$ as:

$$ [\ce{OH-}] = 10^{-5} \times \frac{0.2}{0.4} \tag2$$

Take $-\log$ on both sides of the equation $(2)$:

$$ -\log [\ce{OH-}] = -\log (10^{-5}) - \log \left( \frac{0.2}{0.4}\right) = -\log (10^{-5}) + \log \left( \frac{0.4}{0.2}\right) \tag3$$

The equation $(3)$ is technically the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation for the basic buffer
since $ -\log [\ce{OH-}] = \mathrm{pOH}$, $ -\log (10^{-5}) = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$, $0.2 = [\ce{NH3}]$, and $0.4 = [\ce{NH4+}]$. If rewrite the equation $(3)$ with these notation, you got:

$$ \mathrm{pOH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b} + \log \left( \frac{[\ce{NH4+}]}{[\ce{NH3}]}\right) \tag4$$

So, you have end up with The Henderson-Hasselbalch equation after all. That's because, it is the way the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation derived. If it's not given, you can derived it and use it. Remember the major assumption, $\alpha \lt \lt [\ce{NH3}]$ and $\alpha \lt \lt [\ce{NH4+}]$ in this case, has to be valid.

Comment: Why did you do the calculations considering everything happening for 1 litre of the stuff and not considering 500 mL itself?

Comment: Didn't you see I have calculated the initial concentration in first hand so I don't have to deal with volumes?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But why did you bring the "0.2 M" is what I am not able to understand. As in you wrote 0.2 mol of $\ce{NH_4OH}$ where as it was given that it was 0.1 mol in the question. I thought what you might have done would be "if 0.1 mol in 500mL then, 0.2 mol in 1L". Am I missing something? What I wanted to discuss  was the "extra factor of 0.5" I had when I solved it the way I explained.

Comment: $\pu{1 M} = \pu{1 mol L-1}$. Your solutions are $\pu{0.1 mol}$ in $\pu{0.5 L}$ for both compounds. So, $\pu{M} = \frac{\pu{mol}}{\pu{L}}$, and do your calculations.

Comment: That makes sense to me now, thank you. But I still don't know the "extra factor" of 0.5 I had in the way where I did not convert into standard concentration. Is there an explanation to that?

Comment: To me it seems like you have not counted each molecule of $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ gives 2 ions of $\ce{NH4+}$. Therefore, $[\ce{NH4+}]$ of the solution is $\pu{0.4 M}$ (not $\pu{0.2 M}$; see my calculations).

Comment: I did calculate that, you can see it below the reaction I wrote up, I wrote that 0.1 mol of $\ce{(NH_4)_2 SO_4}$ gives 0.2 mol of $\ce{NH_4^{+}}$.