# Calculate the pH of a buffered solution after adding strong acid

Tags: acid-base, ph, buffer

Calculate the pH of a solution formed by the addition of $0.0020$ moles of $\ce{HCl}$ to $\pu{100.0 mL}$ of $\pu{0.200 M}$ $\ce{CH3NH2}$/ $\ce{0.100 M CH3NH3Cl}$.

$K_\mathrm{b}(\ce{CH3NH2})=4.4\times 10^{-4}$

Any hints will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: We will not help you solve this problem if you don't send us what sort of trials and calculations  you have done previously.

Comment: I know this is a buffer solution that resists a change in pH. I can calculate the pH of the buffer by itself, but how do I proceed after the HCl is added? I just want a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: there is a general method outlined here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60068/how-to-set-up-equation-for-buffer-reaction/95566#95566

Comment: Adding 0.2 millimole HCl to the buffer solution is consuming 0.2 millimole CH3NH2 and creating 0.2 millimole CH3NH3Cl. Go on !

Comment: @Maurice Thanks! Can you take a quick look at my solution?

Comment: It should be widely known that strong acids react with weak bases, forming respective salts as weak acids themselves, what changes conjugate acid/base pair ratio of buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here goes nothing.

$$\ce{CH3NH3+ <=> H+ + CH3NH2}$$

$$K_a(\ce{CH3NH3+})=\frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{CH3NH2}]}{[\ce{CH3NH3+}]}\tag{1}$$

$\displaystyle K_a(\ce{CH3NH3+})=\frac{10^{-14}}{K_b(\ce{CH3NH2})}=\frac{10^{-14}}{4.4\times 10^{-4}}=2.27\times 10^{-11}$

Initial moles of $\ce{CH3NH3+}=0.100\times 0.100=0.010$

Initial moles of $\ce{CH3NH2}=0.100\times 0.200=0.020$

$$\ce{H+ + CH3NH2 -> CH3NH3+}$$

$0.0020$ moles of $\ce{H+}$ react with $0.0020$ moles of $\ce{CH3NH2}$ to form $0.0020$ moles of $\ce{CH3NH3+}$.

Final moles of $\ce{CH3NH3+}=0.010+0.0020=0.012$

Final moles of $\ce{CH3NH2}=0.020-0.0020=0.018$

$V=100.0\text{ mL}=0.1000\text{ L}$

$\displaystyle[\ce{CH3NH3+}]_f=\frac{0.012}{0.1000}=0.120$

$\displaystyle[\ce{CH3NH2}]_f=\frac{0.018}{0.1000}=0.180$

Substituting these values in equation $(1)$, we get

$\displaystyle[\ce{H+}]=\frac{2.27\times 10^{-11}\times[\ce{CH3NH3+}]}{[\ce{CH3NH2}]}=\frac{2.27\times 10^{-11}\times 0.120}{0.180}=1.51\times 10^{-11}$

pH$=-\log[\ce{H+}]=10.82$

Does this look good?

Comment: What was the information you needed when you posted the question? Which comment did it? What would happen if you added 0.03 moles of strong acid instead?

Comment: @Karsten. Why do you ask this question ? Why transform the initial question ? What does it help ?

Comment: @Maurice I was surprised by the self-answer and was wondering what the missing step was initially.  My 3rd question in the comment goes after limits of the recipe shown here.

Comment: @Karsten. OK. I see. Thank you for the information. I was also surprised by the self-answer.