What is the pH when mixing a weak acid and weak base?

I have tried assuming that they react to completion, finding limiting reagent, and then finding pH from there. However, this does not yield the right answer.

There is a general way to do these types of calculations see the answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60068/how-to-set-up-equation-for-buffer-reaction/95566#95566 and also another given in the comments below that answer.

You should at least involve your computation, result and reportedly correct/expected result to evaluate, if the difference is significant, or just the matter of different rounding.

First, find the initial concentrations:
$$[\ce{NH3}]_\mathrm{i} = \frac{\pu{60 mL}}{\pu{135 mL}} \times  \pu{0.45M} = \pu{0.2M}$$
$$[\ce{C6H5COOH}]_\mathrm{i} = [\ce{HA}]_\mathrm{i} = \frac{\pu{75 mL}}{\pu{135 mL}} \times \pu{0.85 M} ≈ \pu{0.4722 M}$$
Then, write out the equilibrium equations that occur
$$\frac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]} = K_\mathrm{a} =6.46 \times 10^{-5} \tag1$$
$$\frac{[\ce{NH4+}][\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{NH3}]} = K_\mathrm{b} = 1.77 \times 10^{-5} \tag2$$
$$[\ce{OH-}] = \frac{10^{-14}}{[\ce{H3O+}]} \tag3$$
Substitute equation 3 into equation 2 to obtain:
$$\frac{[\ce{NH4+}]}{[\ce{NH3}][\ce{H3O+}]} = 1.77 \times 10^{9} \tag4$$
Because the $K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{HA} \gt\gt K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{NH4+}$, assume reaction of $\ce{HA}$ and $\ce{NH3}$ to $\ce{A-}$ and $\ce{NH4+}$ goes to completion.
$$[\ce{HA}]_\mathrm{f} = \pu{0.4722 M} - \pu{0.2 M} = \pu{0.2722 M}$$
$$[\ce{A-}]_\mathrm{f} = \pu{0.2 M}$$
Equation 1 then becomes:
$$[\ce{H3O+}] = 8.792 \times 10^{-5}$$
with $\mathrm{pH}$ being
$$\mathrm{pH} = -\log([\ce{H3O+}]) ≈ 4.056 ≈ 4.06$$
Given that the $\mathrm{pH}$ is nowhere near a place where $[\ce{H3O+}] \gt [\ce{A-}]$, the calculations should hold.
P.S.: Using charge balance to solve for $\mathrm{pH}$ instead of assuming the reaction goes to completion gives a value of around 4.0562, which is decently close. All you need to do to perform charge balance is to use equations 1 and 2 above, and note that $$[\ce{A-}] ≈ [\ce{NH4+}]+[\ce{H3O+}]$$

I use $\ce{HA}$ for $\ce{C6H5COOH}$ and $\ce{B}$ for $\ce{NH3}$.
The analytical concentrations after mixing both solutions can be calculated as:
$$ [\ce{HA}]_0 = \frac{75 \times \pu{0.85 M}}{75+60} = \pu{0.472 M}$$
$$ [\ce{B}]_0 = \frac{60 \times \pu{0.45 M}}{75+60} = \pu{0.2 M}$$
Now consider the following the reactions.
$$\ce{HA + H2O -> H3O+ + A-} \quad (x)$$
$$\ce{B + H2O -> OH- + BH+} \quad (y)$$
$$\ce{OH- + H3O+ -> 2H2O} \quad (z)$$
I denote the extent of each reaction in terms of concentrations as $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively.
The equilibrium concentrations are then:
$$ [\ce{HA}] = [\ce{HA}]_0 - x = \pu{0.472 M} - x$$
$$ [\ce{A}] = x $$
$$ [\ce{H3O+}] = x - z $$
$$ [\ce{B}] = [\ce{B}]_0 - y = \pu{0.2 M} - y$$
$$ [\ce{BH+}] = y $$
$$ [\ce{OH-}] = y - z $$
Thus we have the following equations:
$$K_a = \frac{[\ce{A-}][\ce{H3O+}]}{[\ce{HA}]} = \pu{6.45E-5} = \frac{x (x - z)}{\pu{0.472 M} - x}$$
$$K_b = \frac{[\ce{BH+}][\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{B}]} = \pu{1.77E-5} = \frac{y (y - z)}{\pu{0.2 M} - y}$$
$$K_w = [\ce{H3O+}][\ce{OH-}] = \pu{1E-14} = (x-z)(y-z)$$
Solving for $(x,y,z)$ might require some nonlinear equation solver. The solution is:
$$ x = 0.200086575630759 $$
$$ y = 0.199998713961671 $$
$$ z = 0.199998713847856 $$
(There may be other solutions to the system of equations, but this is the only one that respects all concentrations must be positive)
Therefore,
$$ [\ce{HA}] = [\ce{HA}]_0 - x = \pu{0.272 M} $$
$$ [\ce{A}] = x = \pu{0.2 M}$$
$$ [\ce{H3O+}] = x - z = \pu{8.786E-5 M}$$
$$ [\ce{B}] = [\ce{B}]_0 - y = \pu{1.286E-6 M}$$
$$ [\ce{BH+}] = y = \pu{0.2 M} $$
$$ [\ce{OH-}] = y - z = \pu{1,138E-10 M} $$
Finally we conclude
$$\ce{pH} = -\log([\ce{H3O+}]) = -\log(\pu{8.786E-5 M}) = \pu{4.056}$$
